# Morse Code I can't solve

Tags: cipher, mystery

Help me decode this morse code into plain text.
I can't solve it because it has no spaces.

[image: Morse Code]

Text version: ..-.-..--.-.-...-...-..---.--.....-....-.
Ending Part Might be: -- -.-- ... . .-.. ..-.
"myself" ??

Comment: According to http://www.jbowman.com/remorse/ there are over a quadrillion possible space combinations for this code. Good luck to anyone solving this.

Comment: Do we have any idea as to what it might say?

Comment: -- -.-- ... . .-.. ..-. This ending part is "Myself"

Comment: Morse code is generally impossible to solve without spaces unless you're *very* lucky with your guesses.

Comment: @Deusovi: It shouldn't be too difficult to write a program to brute-force the possibilities. If we assume every word belongs to the dictionary, the vast majority of the quadrillion possibilities will be dropped early, making the search-space feasible.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: I have code to do exactly this somewhere. It was part of extra credit for a code challenge. There should only be a few possibilities that are grammatically acceptable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A bit gloomy but we can break it up this way

> .. 
>  -.-./.-/-. 
>  -.-/../.-../.-..
>  --/-.--/..././.-../..-.

which is

> I can kill myself

Comment: I just confirmed that using the jbowman link.  Gloo-my.

Answer (score 12):

There are many possibilities, but this seems to fit letter-by-letter, word-by-word, and it makes a grammatically valid sentence:

> ```
> .. / -.-. .- -. -.-. . .-.. . -.. / -- -.-- ... . .-.. ..-.
> ```
>
> ```
> I  / c    a  n  c    e l    e d  /  m  y    s   e l    f
> ```
>
> **I canceled myself**

Hopefully that means something in context.

Method:
Start at known letter boundaries (end, beginning, guess common words). Try all possibilities; attempt longest letters first, since they are rarest, and have the fewest possible follow-ups, so they are easier to rule out.